# Mirror zoom magnification between adjacent windows?

Tags: 3d-view

I have two adjacent viewports, one in Front Ortho, the other in Right Ortho, so I can edit the same model from the front and side.  Is there any way to lock/mirror/match the magnification between the two, so that if I zoom in/out in one, the other zooms in/out to the same degree also?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Quad View for that. 
Set up those 3 views so each of them is different (top, side and front). Then turn on its *Lock* and *Box* features :

[image]

You can zoom and grab those views simultaneously:

[image]

Comment: The shortcut to enter Quad View is **Ctrl+Alt+Q**

Comment: Wonderfully helpful--even more streamlined than what I'd hoped for.  Thank you!  And for any supernoobs like myself, you get to that Display menu with the hotkey 'n'.  Thanks!